# FB.api is the true on instead of FB.Data.query?

Tags: fbml, facebook-insights

In the queries in FB.api we wrote, end_time has to be written like a UNIX time ie 12423492349 not like 2011-01-03 in this function. I think this end_time function becomes a bug for the API and now there is no of that.
Insights started not to come to me on the beginning of January,2012 and I had to change FB.Data.query to FB.api but the deprecated metrics brings either empty datas or some datas for some days or for any metrics. 
Anybody knows this issue or solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there were many insights that were deprecated with Facebook's new policy of 90 notice.  See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/ for the complete list of what was removed.

Of note, FBML is deprecated and has only a few months left before it goes away completely.

Comment: yes I saw this page on Nov,2011 but I really dont understand the sentence there :"we are deprecating some old insights. These metrics are marked as deprecated throughout this document" so it means I think old insights would be gone away not the metrics but in real every thing goes down :) Fb is a strange platform that it always keeps changing itself but with no notification and changes are definitely from beginning to the end. I want to know that how do we query insights with FB.api? like fb.api("query='select metric,value from insights where ...';")

Comment: It's also possible that there were some bugs in their data collection and or data analysis or even a bug in they way they collect the results for the call.   What you might be seeing is the difference in either it being bad back then and now it's fine, or it was fine back then, and now they introduced a bug.  If you have hard facts, then I'd highly recommend you file a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs to see what facebook will do about it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I got only some insights for my pageids but only in graph explorer with the link "....pageid/insights" not for my codes (fb.data or fb.api) still..yes you right for some people in fb may be it is now finer with these changes, but clearly I see that here lots of people dont like this change and dont get full data of their ids. they always are in a case that "we get insights more or less but it is a little coming properly" :) I dont agree with that because I think API is a thing that makes our lifes easier not changable or complicated, as fb does :) I will write a bug also

Comment: Be sure to edit your question with the bug number, so others can see too.  Thanks!